# How do I change the position of "sidebar first" for the Arabic version of website?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Can I change the position of the "sidebar first" if I change the website language?

More Details: My default website language is now English, and my "sidebar first" is in left position. This is what I want: to change the position of the "sidebar first" if I make the website in the Arabic language.

Comment: yes, but how depends on the theme, and how you're implementing the multi-language site

Comment: I have the interlocalization module and all configuration by default

Comment: that's not the name of a module I am aware of... do you mean internationalization?

Comment: Yes that's it !!!

Comment: then J.Reynolds answer should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module.

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.

Make sure that Multilingual select which is part of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module is also installed (this will provide the proper condition).

You can now create a new context that has a condition of 'Language' and a reaction of 'Blocks'.

You will create a condition-reaction pair for two cases. First for all the LTR languages, second for all the RTL languages.

Allthough this does not directly answer your question as to regions, you can play around with the reactions, such as template suggestions etc to achieve your objective.

Comment: You'r answer dosen't help me

Comment: @SeifBh why doesn't this help you - you need to provide more information - does it not work, does it not work the way you want, do you not want to include a module for some reason, etc. Your response doesn't help us, help you